# Insert a block of code as a paragraph

Tags: code

Looking to display several lines of code in my report as one block, the same way that code is displayed on Stack Exchange. For inline code I've been using `\tikzhl` and `\texttt`:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\tikzhl}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(X.base)]
 \node[fill=black!10] (X) {#1};}
```

This seems a good solution for code integrated in paragraphs: [image]

But for several lines as their own paragraph it is not ideal:
[image]
What I would like to do is have it appear as the following with one bounding grey box:

```
Found 20 valid images for calibration
DIM=(1920, 1080)
K=np.array([[1374.9140598345757, 0.0, 996.2559942548266], [0.0, 1376.7481511557473, 541.0310811091442], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
D=np.array([[-0.017077674858759682], [-0.30267173652198426], [1.7521950786149205], [-3.054359786737165]])
```

Adding a new line where it is wider than the page margins if possible, although I can do this manually if not possible.

Thanks in advance. Using Texmaker with MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: You have `listings` and `minted` specifically for this purpose. Ti*k*Z should not be used in this case.

Comment: If you want to customize more that what these two packages can handle, you can use `tcolorbox` with `listings` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I keep your `\tikzhl` command, but it won't work with something like `\tikzhl{\documentclass}` (which is supposed to output `\documentclass`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!10},
    breaklines=true
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\tikzhl}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(X.base)]
 \node[fill=black!10,font=\ttfamily,inner sep=1pt] (X) {#1};}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Found 20 valid images for calibration
DIM=(1920, 1080)
K=np.array([[1374.9140598345757, 0.0, 996.2559942548266], [0.0, 1376.7481511557473, 541.0310811091442], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
D=np.array([[-0.017077674858759682], [-0.30267173652198426], [1.7521950786149205], [-3.054359786737165]])
\end{lstlisting}

Package \tikzhl{listings} can do it for you.
\end{document}
```

[image]